# Remove Extra padding of UILable

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

I am working on a app that support both RTL And LTR.
I am using Monserat font for RTL language and i need to use Cairo font for LTR language. but i am facing an issue in Arabic when using Ciaro font, there is extra padding on labels so views are not looking good in Arabic.
Please have a look in given screen shot [image]

Comment: Hello same issue here did you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom class of `UILabel`, which will support **RTL** and **LTR** directions.

For example:

```
class MirroringLabel: UILabel {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if UIApplication.isRightToLeftLayoutDirection() {
            self.textAlignment = .right
        } else {
            self.textAlignment = .left
        }
    }
}
```

And change in Storyboard class of your label from `UILabel` to `MirroringLabel`